# How to download a test app on a test page under Facebook for Developers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So the original issue is that my company needs access to clients Facebook page ratings and reviews.  After sorting through the docs, I've settled on the process where the Client's FB Page will download our app to give our app manages_pages permissions/ rights and such.

The problem I have is that I need to test this before preceding with App review submission.

I have create a Test Page and Test users whom have submitted reviews and ratings on that test page; however, I need help trying to figure out how to download our App (which is in development mode) on to the Test Page so I can test the permissions granted.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: You don’t “download” apps to pages. A page admin has to log in to your app and grant it the permission.

Comment: @misorude So then I wouldn't be able to test my Test App with a Test Page?  

I would have to apply my App for the Review process first before I could test it?  Just to clarify, my app won't have an UI nor it isn't a game, it's just for the purpose of getting client Ratings and reviews.

Comment: Why not, the test page has an admin, too, no?